# Angular2 - accordion that keeps multiple sections open

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, accordion

I have some posts which are loaded on ngOnInit and action togglePost that load items for selected post.
But I need to keep open various posts with loaded items.

```
<accordion-group (togglePost)="togglePost($event)">
  <accordion *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post">                          
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of items">
       {{item.name}}
     </li>
  </ul>
  </accordion>          
</accordion-group>
```

How can I implement accordion that keeps multiple sections open at the same time?

Comment: which ui framework are you using ??

Comment: I am using Angular

Comment: Define "Various posts" ...How do you identify these various posts ?whats the condition ?

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya I identify them under the id
 for example post - Books have such items:
- author
- genre
- pages qnty
- other

Comment: So you have the condition to identify those posts ,just you need to know how to keep the open ? and also please show the link of the accordion you are using

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya
I am using this [accordion] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113446/how-can-i-create-simple-accordion-with-angular-2) created by Tiep Phan

Comment: can you create a plunk for the same ? the plunk in the link is broken..it looks like you just have to add active class to those accordions which you want it to be open

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to determine if an accordion is open. Then assign your items found from togglePost to each post item. This way you are not always overwriting your component's items property

```
// posts
[
  {
    items: [], // store this post's items
    isOpen: false, // determines if accordion is open
    otherFields...
  }...
]
```

Then the togglePost method is responsible for loading the items & toggling the view

Finally use an ngIf or [hidden] directive to show/hide the items. Also have your inner ngFor use each post's items instead of the component's items property. Now multiple accordions can be open at once.

```
<accordion-group (togglePost)="togglePost($event)">
  <accordion *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post">                          
    <ul [hidden]="!post.isOpen">
      <li *ngFor="let item of post.items">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </accordion>          
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: Wont this stop rendering of some parts if isOpen is false ?Question is to open or close accordion ,not to stop them from rendering ...atleast thats what i understood !

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya you are right. we can use the [hidden] directive to hide instead of un-render if that is the intention of the OP.

Comment: Nope ,again this will eliminate a part of the accordion itself .It should be closed not hidden

Answer (score 0):

You have to add active class to the accordion selector.Since it is done in the child component ,you have to send whether if should be active or not as a input to the child.Change your template like this

```
 <tp-accordion *ngFor="let post of posts" [title]="post.title" 
 [active]="condition()">
 {{ post.body }}
 </tp-accordion>
```

and in the `condition()` function,do the condition checking and return true or false .

```
ondition(){
    if(this.yourcondition){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

See the working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kamRSvJKuOSl6J9NIdpO?p=preview).Hope it helps